# phphow to use the incremented values in other php files

Tags: php

I have created a function in php to incremenent a value whenever i called it .
code for inc.php

```
<?php
function increment()
    {
        static $i=0;
        $i=$i+1;
        echo $i;
    }
```

?>

when i am calling it from one php file it is giving me the right output as 1 . if i am calling it from another php file it is again showing me 1 . 
eg.

there are 3 php file

a1.php
a2.php
a3.php

when i called it form a1.php it is showing me 1, just after that if i am executing it a2.php is again showing 1.
I want when a call increment function from a1.php it should show 1,if i call a2.php consecutively it should show 2, and from a3.php it should 3

code of a1.php

```
<?php include('inc.php');increment();?>
```

code for a2.php

`<?php
include('inc.php');
increment();
?>` 
plz help me with my problem . thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't at all descriptive. Do you have classes in these files? Static variables? Post an abbreviated version. If you're only going off of the file name, why not get the number from the file name and use that as your increment, since they seem to be inline?

Comment: i don't have classes in these files. i am simply calling increment function from these file.

Comment: Can you post code showing how you are including a1.php in the other files, and how you are calling it?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`session`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: i have posted all my code above

Comment: What jack said: session (or cookie) would be the best option. You could of course POST or GET every request, but that seems stupid.

Answer (score 0):

at first you can create new php page , say 'function.php' with a function for increment of a variable . through which the value will increase. then include function.php in all three pages and link the page with the button through which you are switching to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't understand how PHP works, variables are instanciated when you call the page. Then they are destroyed.

So when you call a1.php or a2.php, your variable $i, even if this is a static variable, is destroyed after the end of the script.

If you want to use both php files, you should have a look at require()